# Cron backup tasks

Tags: linux, backup

I have been disconnected from the topic for a long time.

Some time ago, I was used to use crontab in order to perform a task each some time. I need to perform a shell script each 30 minutes:

```
#!/bin/bash
SNAPSHOT=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
docker exec es curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/$SNAPSHOT?wait_for_completion=true"
```

I'm facing up with two approaches:

1. Create a systemctl service,
2. Create a crontab.

Which's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: I'd argue crontab is slightly better, because otherwise you create an unnecessary extra daemon.

Comment: You mean a systemctl _timer_? A service doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Yes. I meant that. Why does it have not sense? Otherwise, I've added this line on `crontab -e`: `0,30 * * * * root docker exec es sh /usr/local/bin/snapshot.sh`. Nevertheless, it's launched but the file it generates are not sent on S3... I've took a look on `/var/log/cron` but only appears that: `Jan 20 05:30:01 platform-prod CROND[16409]: (root) CMD (root docker exec es sh /usr/local/bin/snapshot.sh)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you write you have added a cron job like this :

```
0,30 * * * * root docker exec es sh /usr/local/bin/snapshot.sh
```

From your script, it would be :

```
0,30 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/snapshot.sh
```

With that, your script will be executed with `root` rights. And in `/var/log/cron` you will have: `Jan 20 05:30:01 platform-prod CROND[16409]: (root) CMD (root /usr/local/bin/snapshot.sh)`